# Capitalize first letter in Ruby with UTF-8 strings with exceptions

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to capitalize each word of a UTF-8 string. However, I need the function to ignore some special characters in the beginning of words, like "(-.,". The function will be used to capitalize song titles which can look like this:

marko, gabriel boni, simple jack - recall (original mix)

...would output:

Marko, Gabriel Boni, Simple Jack - Recall (Original Mix)

It should also be able to capitalize UTF-8 chars like "å" > "Å". "é" > "É".

Comment: You mean languages using the Roman characters, right? Not dividing a UTF-8 string "ご飯を食べた" into "ご飯", "を", "食べた".

Comment: Sorry, yes that's correct. I wasn't sure how to describe it. But characters like "åäöéèí" etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"åbc".mb_chars.capitalize
#=> "Åbc" 
"ébc".mb_chars.capitalize.to_s
#=> "Ébc"
```

**UPD**

And to ignore none word chars:

```
string = "-åbc"
str = string.match(/^(\W*)(.*)/)
str[1] + str[2].mb_chars.capitalize.to_s
#=> "-Åbc"
```

Comment: It seems that mb_char is part of RoR.

Answer (score 8):

Is there something why Unicode::capitalize method from [unicode library](http://rubygems.org/gems/unicode) does not suit your needs ?

```
irb(main):013:0> require 'unicode'
=> true
irb(main):014:0> begin Unicode::capitalize 'åäöéèí' rescue $stderr.print "unicode error\n" end
=> "Åäöéèí"
irb(main):015:0> begin Unicode::capitalize '-åäöéèí' rescue $stderr.print "unicode error\n" end 
=> "-åäöéèí"
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this and wanted to filter a lot of things.

I created a constants file `initializers/constants.rb`

```
letters = ("a".."z").collect
numbers = ("1".."9").collect
symbols = %w[! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ - + = | \] { } : ; ' " ? / > . < , ]
FILTER = letters + numbers + symbols
```

And then just did a check to see if it was in my filter:

```
if !FILTER.include?(c)
    #no
else
    #yes
end
```

You can also check the value of the unicode but you need to know the range or specific values. I did this with chinese characters, so that is where I got my values. I will post some code just to give you an idea:

```
def check(char)
   char = char.unpack('U*').first
   if char >= 0x4E00 && char <= 0x9FFF
     return true
   end
   if char >= 0x3400 && char <= 0x4DBF
     return true
   end
   if char >= 0x20000 && char <= 0x2A6DF
     return true
   end
   if char >= 0x2A700 && char <= 0x2B73F
     return true
   end
   return false
 end
```

You need to know the specific values here of course.